# Is a Test dataset necessary?

Tags: machine-learning

I am training a CNN machine learning model which detects and classifies cardiac arrhythmia into various categories. I have however used the test set for my validation set and now I have a validation accuracy of 98%. Do I need to have a test set or can I just use my validation accuracy as a final indication of how good my model is?

Comment: Not sure if this holds for CNN's, but for ANN's splitting your data into 80-20 (test-validation) data was recommended to show how your network can handle items which weren't in the training set. Having the accuracy based solely on the test data can be misleading

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is best to have a training, validation and test set. You can get a good estimation of how your model generalizes to images it has not seen before by just using the validation accuracy provided you did not bias the model based on the validation set. For example if you use an adjustable learning rate based on monitoring of the validation loss you are to a degree introducing a "bias" in your model toward the specific validation set. In that case it would be best to test your model against an independent test set. They will probably have similar accuracy but this is not always the case. If the probability distribution of your validation  set is not representative of the full probability range of potential class images an independent test set with a more encompassing distribution may yield less accurate results.